# Vue: Past event target value is giving me an empty string on the first paste

Tags: string, vue.js, paste

My input field is empty and I paste a string in I get back an empty string. If I paste it again it shows me the previous pasted value. How do I capture the first paste value?

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    
  <h3>{{cat}}</h3>
  <input @paste="testfunction" :style="{border:'solid black thick'}"/>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },

  data: () => ({
    cat:'meow'
  }),
  methods:{
    testfunction(event:any){
      console.log(event.target.value)
      this.cat = event.target.value
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have answered this by using await navigator.clipboard.readText(). I don't know if this is the best solution, but it's working for me.